Делаю бота telegram на telebot, и такая ошибка: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400...? Как испавить?
Ошибка: telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: Text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Выберите начало номера:')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Г1', callback_data='delete'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Другой номер'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите начало номера:', reply_markup=markup)```


Открывает документацию Bot API, читаем про инлайн кнопки:

InlineKeyboardButton
This object represents one button of an inline keyboard. You must use
exactly one of the optional fields.

У тебя же в коде, во второй кнопке, только текст. Нужно прописать что-нибудь еще: url, callback_data и тд
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Выберите начало номера:')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Г1', callback_data='delete'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Другой номер', callback_data='delete2'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите начало номера:', reply_markup=markup)

